# Pass name of button to click event

Tags: c#, wpf

I am generating a number of buttons with similar or identical content and was hoping to use the names they are given to differentiate them. As the program is creating the buttons dynamically I can't create a separate event for them all and instead need to be able to grab the name to be able to know which button triggered the event.

Is there a way to pass through the name of a button to the click event it initiates? the sender object seems to contain the content but not the name.

It is for a event like this:

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //getname of button
        Canvas.Children.Remove(//name of button\\)
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not familiar with WPF. If this answer appears to be a junk, I'll delete it.

In ASP.Net, we can cast to a button to get the sender's information. Something like this -

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var button = sender as Button;
    button.Name
}
```

Comment: This won't actually work, because by default, buttons and other elements in WPF don't have anything assigned to Name.  They're just an empty string.

Comment: This actually seemed to have worked. I need to test it a bit more to make sure it works in all cases but you may have just saved me a world of trouble!

Comment: This allowed me to grab and save the name of the button as well as the button itself to be used in further events. Thank you exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 6):

Far as I know, WPF does not even assign anything to the `Name` property automatically - that's just for developers to assign so we can reference the control.

However, you should be able to just pass in the sender to the remove method since it accepts a UIElement argument which Button is derived from.

```
Canvas.Children.Remove((Button)sender);
```

Comment: The program assigns a unique name for each button when it creates it. Also trying Canvas.Children.Remove(sender); returns the error: "The best overloaded method match for 'System.Windows.Controls.UIElementCollection.Remove(System.Windows.UIElement)' has some invalid arguments"

Comment: That error is caused because "sender" is an "object."  Cast it to a "Button" and it will then qualify as a UIElement.  This answer is correct.

Comment: ah yes once I do this it does indeed work. The name itself is what I needed to grab though as it is used in more than just the case to remove itself. I have never seen the (Button) usage to define something. I wonder what else I could simplify in my code using a similar method.

Comment: Yeah, your post didn't mention that you were assigning a name to the controls yourself, so Win's method does work.  Casting to (Type) is very common though, to comply with strong typing constraints.  Note that it's not actually changing the type,  it's more like revealing the true name of a person under an assumed alias. In this case, the assumed alias of Object.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps getting at the control's name will work for you

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  Control control = (Control)sender;
  Canvas.Children.Remove(control.Name);
}
```